Deepgram's Live Speech-To-Text Integration with Twilio, in Python?
I have been intrigued by Bland and Vapi, and wanted to make my own AI calling assistant. For the calling part, I decided to use Twilio. I tried using AssemblyAI's live speech-to-text model, but that requires me to give my credit card info. So I tried using Deepgram. Problem is, none of my solutions have been working thus far. There are almost no good tutorials on this problem, considering that every other speech-to-text model does have their own tutorial, multiple times even.
Latest, I got stuck at a very confusing part of the program. Take a look at the code alongwith the terminal output.
Here is the code from main.py:
import os
import asyncio

from flask import Flask, request, Response
from flask_sock import Sock
import ngrok
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import Connect, VoiceResponse, Say, Stream
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

from twilio_transcriber import TwilioTranscriber

# Flask settings
PORT = 5000
DEBUG = False
INCOMING_CALL_ROUTE = '/'
WEBSOCKET_ROUTE = '/realtime'

# Twilio authentication
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
api_key = os.environ['TWILIO_API_KEY_SID']
api_secret = os.environ['TWILIO_API_SECRET']
client = Client(api_key, api_secret, account_sid)

# Twilio phone number to call
TWILIO_NUMBER = os.environ['TWILIO_NUMBER']

# ngrok authentication
ngrok.set_auth_token(os.getenv("NGROK_AUTHTOKEN"))
app = Flask(__name__)
sock = Sock(app)

@app.route(INCOMING_CALL_ROUTE, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def receive_call():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        xml = f"""
<Response>
    <Say>
        You will currently be talking to an AI assistant. By continuing this call, you are consenting for the transcript of this call to be anonymously recorded and used for improving our AI calling functions.
    </Say>
    <Connect>
        <Stream url='wss://{request.host}{WEBSOCKET_ROUTE}' />
    </Connect>
</Response>
""".strip()
        return Response(xml, mimetype='text/xml')
    else:
        return f"This is the calling URL for any incoming number."

@app.route(INCOMING_CALL_ROUTE + "num/<Number>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def receive_outgoing_call(Number):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        xml = f"""
<Response>
    <Say>
        You will currently be talking to an AI assistant. By continuing this call, you are consenting for the transcript of this call to be anonymously recorded and used for improving our AI calling functions.
    </Say>
    <Connect>
        <Stream url='wss://{request.host}{WEBSOCKET_ROUTE}/{Number}' />
    </Connect>
</Response>
""".strip()
        return Response(xml, mimetype='text/xml')
    else:
        return f"This is the calling URL for {Number}."

@sock.route(WEBSOCKET_ROUTE + "/<Number>")
def transcription_websocket(ws, Number):
    asyncio.run(handle_websocket(ws, Number))

async def handle_websocket(ws, Number):
    transcriber = TwilioTranscriber(ws, Number)
    await transcriber.connect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        # Open Ngrok tunnel
        listener = ngrok.forward(f"http://localhost:{PORT}")
        print(f"Ngrok tunnel opened at {listener.url()} for port {PORT}")
        NGROK_URL = listener.url()

        # Set ngrok URL to be the webhook for the appropriate Twilio number
        twilio_numbers = client.incoming_phone_numbers.list()
        twilio_number_sid = [num.sid for num in twilio_numbers if num.phone_number == TWILIO_NUMBER][0]
        client.incoming_phone_numbers(twilio_number_sid).update(account_sid, voice_url=f"{NGROK_URL}{INCOMING_CALL_ROUTE}")

        call = client.calls.create(
            url=NGROK_URL + "/num/+91xxxxxxxxxx",
            to='+91xxxxxxxxxx',
            from_=TWILIO_NUMBER,
        )
        print(call.sid)

        # run the app
        app.run(port=PORT, debug=DEBUG)
    finally:
        # Always disconnect the ngrok tunnel
        ngrok.disconnect()

Here is the code from twilio_transcriber.py:
import os
import json
import base64
import asyncio
import websockets
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pydub import AudioSegment

load_dotenv()

DEEPGRAM_API_KEY = os.getenv('DEEPGRAM_API_KEY')
TWILIO_SAMPLE_RATE = 8000  # Hz
DEEPGRAM_WS_URL = 'wss://api.deepgram.com/v1/listen?encoding=mulaw&sample_rate=8000&channels=2&multichannel=true'

class TwilioTranscriber:
    def __init__(self, twilio_ws, number):
        self.twilio_ws = twilio_ws
        self.deepgram_ws = None
        self.ph_no = number
        self.audio_queue = asyncio.Queue()
        self.callsid_queue = asyncio.Queue()

    async def connect(self):
        headers = {'Authorization': f'Token {DEEPGRAM_API_KEY}'}
        print('Connecting to Deepgram WebSocket...')
        try:
            self.deepgram_ws = await websockets.connect(DEEPGRAM_WS_URL, extra_headers=headers)
            print('Connected to Deepgram WebSocket.')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Failed to connect to Deepgram WebSocket: {e}')
            return

        await asyncio.wait([
            asyncio.ensure_future(self.deepgram_sender()),
            asyncio.ensure_future(self.deepgram_receiver()),
            asyncio.ensure_future(self.twilio_receiver())
        ])

    async def deepgram_sender(self):
        print('deepgram_sender started')
        while True:
            chunk = await self.audio_queue.get()
            if chunk is None:
                break
            try:
                await self.deepgram_ws.send(chunk)
                print('Sent audio chunk to Deepgram.')
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'Failed to send audio chunk to Deepgram: {e}')
                break

    async def deepgram_receiver(self):
        print('deepgram_receiver started')
        callsid = await self.callsid_queue.get()
        async for message in self.deepgram_ws:
            try:
                print(f'Received message from Deepgram: {message}')
                transcription = json.loads(message)
                print(f'Transcription from {self.ph_no}: {transcription}')
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'Failed to process Deepgram message: {e}')
                break

    async def twilio_receiver(self):
        print('twilio_receiver started')
        BUFFER_SIZE = 20 * 160
        inbuffer = bytearray()
        outbuffer = bytearray()
        inbound_chunks_started = False
        outbound_chunks_started = False
        latest_inbound_timestamp = 0
        latest_outbound_timestamp = 0

        async for message in self.twilio_ws:
            print(f'Received message from Twilio: {message}')
            try:
                data = json.loads(message)
                print(f'Parsed JSON data: {data}')
                
                if data['event'] == 'start':
                    start = data['start']
                    callsid = start['callSid']
                    self.callsid_queue.put_nowait(callsid)
                    print(f'Received start event for callSid: {callsid}')
                elif data['event'] == 'connected':
                    print('Received connected event')
                    continue
                elif data['event'] == 'media':
                    media = data['media']
                    chunk = base64.b64decode(media['payload'])
                    print(f'Received media chunk: {len(chunk)} bytes')
                    
                    if media['track'] == 'inbound':
                        if inbound_chunks_started:
                            if latest_inbound_timestamp + 20 < int(media['timestamp']):
                                bytes_to_fill = 8 * (int(media['timestamp']) - (latest_inbound_timestamp + 20))
                                inbuffer.extend(b'\xff' * bytes_to_fill)
                        else:
                            inbound_chunks_started = True
                            latest_inbound_timestamp = int(media['timestamp'])
                            latest_outbound_timestamp = int(media['timestamp']) - 20
                        latest_inbound_timestamp = int(media['timestamp'])
                        inbuffer.extend(chunk)
                    elif media['track'] == 'outbound':
                        if latest_outbound_timestamp + 20 < int(media['timestamp']):
                            bytes_to_fill = 8 * (int(media['timestamp']) - (latest_outbound_timestamp + 20))
                            outbuffer.extend(b'\xff' * bytes_to_fill)
                        latest_outbound_timestamp = int(media['timestamp'])
                        outbuffer.extend(chunk)
                elif data['event'] == 'stop':
                    print('Received stop event')
                    break

                while len(inbuffer) >= BUFFER_SIZE and len(outbuffer) >= BUFFER_SIZE:
                    asinbound = AudioSegment(inbuffer[:BUFFER_SIZE], sample_width=1, frame_rate=TWILIO_SAMPLE_RATE, channels=1)
                    asoutbound = AudioSegment(outbuffer[:BUFFER_SIZE], sample_width=1, frame_rate=TWILIO_SAMPLE_RATE, channels=1)
                    mixed = AudioSegment.from_mono_audiosegments(asinbound, asoutbound)
                    self.audio_queue.put_nowait(mixed.raw_data)
                    inbuffer = inbuffer[BUFFER_SIZE:]
                    outbuffer = outbuffer[BUFFER_SIZE:]
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'Error processing Twilio message: {e}')
                break

        self.audio_queue.put_nowait(b'')

# The code below is just for demonstration purposes and assumes you have an established websocket connection `twilio_ws` and a phone number `number`.
# You would need to replace these with your actual websocket connection and phone number.
# Example usage:
# transcriber = TwilioTranscriber(twilio_ws, number)
# asyncio.run(transcriber.connect())

Here is the terminal output:
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
Ngrok tunnel opened at https://7018-2405-201-8026-300f-3828-7548-4a2-67a.ngrok-free.app for port 5000
CAca39dfd003f34e29a1d0fef5f89aeb59
 * Serving Flask app 'main'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2024 10:45:02] "POST /num/+919382280814 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Connecting to Deepgram WebSocket...
Connected to Deepgram WebSocket.
deepgram_sender started
deepgram_receiver started
twilio_receiver started

If you think that I pasted the incomplete terminal output, no. It actually gets stuck here, and I get no response from either my phone call or the terminal.
